# Dynamic vs JObject for JSON deserialization

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

Let's say I have the following string:

```
 string MyString = @"{""name"":""John"",""url"":""https://www.john.com""}";
```

And I can deserialize it two ways like:

```
JObject jobj = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(MyString);
dynamic jobj2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(MyString);
```

When I do a GetType of both objects I get for both:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject
```

Yet when I log jobj2.name I get **John** but when I log jobj.name I get:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' does not contain a definition for 'name' and no extension method 'name' accepting a first argument of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject'
```

And have to call it like jobj["name"]

What is the reason for the different syntax since both are JObject?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, as `jobj.name` throws the same error. Note that `((dynamic)jobj2).name` _will_ print 'John', as will `(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(MyString) as dynamic).name`. Just another example of the weird behaviours of `dynamic`: having inherited a code base that used it to parse Json, I got rid of it as soon as I could and would never use it again. Just my opinion.

Comment: Think about it:  `JOjbect` is a defined type (like `string` or `JsonConvert`). Can you dynamically add properties to a defined type? How would you be able to call `.name` on something that doesn't `name` property/field? `dynamic` is named such for a reason:  it's late binding. Late binding means that properties are defined at runtime, not compile time. `dynamic` can have a property called `.name` because that property gets created at runtime during the deserialization.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that `JObject` (or rather one of its base classes) implements  [`IDynamicMetaObjectProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.idynamicmetaobjectprovider). This interface allows objects to customize how `dynamic` expressions are resolved, rather than just reflecting over their public members. This is also how [`ExpandoObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.expandoobject) works.